# Add gaps between rectangles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, coordinates

Given some rectangles, I have to add gaps between them. For every rectangle, I've `x` coordinate, `y` coordinate, `dx` representing the width, and `dy` representing the height. The origin is on the top left corner. I'm using HTML canvas. The following image explains the problem.

[visual representation of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EXXw.jpg)

Here, all the blue boxes in the second image represent the gap or offset by which a specific rectangle's dimension will be reduced.

I tried the following code. Here, `parentX` is the x coordinate of the parent box, `parentY` is the y coordinate of the parent, `parentDx` is the width, and `parentDy` is the height of the parent box.

```js
const padRectangle = (rectangle, parentX, parentY, parentDx, parentDy) => {
    const padding = this.boxPadding
    const { x, y, dx, dy } = rectangle

    // console.log("Rect:", x, y, x + dx, y + dy)
    // console.log("Parent:", parentX, parentY, parentX + parentDx, parentY + parentDy)

    if (x != parentX) {
      rectangle.x += padding;
    }

    if (y != parentY) {
      rectangle.y += padding;
    }

    if ((x + dx) != (parentX + parentDx)) {
      rectangle.dx -= padding;
    }

    if ((y + dy) != (parentY + parentDy)) {
      rectangle.dy -= padding;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Gaps should appear only where two rectangles meet? In your mockup there is no gap with the canvas border, is it what you need? How are defined the rectangles?